# Pandas - Moving Average without current row values

Tags: python, pandas, moving-average

I have a pandas [dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVtvf.png)

| date | product | quant |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-11-01 | a | 234 |
| 2021-11-01 | b | 837 |
| 2021-12-01 | a | 930 |
| 2022-01-01 | a | 362 |
| 2022-01-01 | b | 859 |
| 2022-02-01 | a |  |
| 2022-02-01 | b |  |
| 2022-03-01 | a |  |
| 2022-03-01 | b |  |
| 2022-04-01 | a |  |
| 2022-04-01 | b |  |

```
 input = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2021-11-01','2021-11-01','2021-12-01','2021-01-01','2021-01-01','2022-02-01', '2022-02-01','2022-03-01','2022-03-01','2022-04-04'],\
             'product':['a','b','a','a','a','b','a','b','a','b'],
            'quant':[234,837,930,362,859,0,0,0,0,0]})
```

I need to calculate the moving 3 month average for future dates (at least 1 year to the future) (in this case for 2022-02-01 it would be `[2021-11-01+2021-12-01-2022-01-01]`, for 2022-04-01 it would be `[2022-01-01+2022-02-01+2022-03-01]` and for 2022-12-01 it would be `[2022-09-01+2022-10-01+2022-11-01]`). In other words, I need to calculate moving average of **3 previous rows** without **current row** value.

[My desired output is: *](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1BUZ.png)

| date | product | quant |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-11-01 | a | 234 |
| 2021-11-01 | b | 837 |
| 2021-12-01 | a | 930 |
| 2022-01-01 | a | 362 |
| 2022-01-01 | b | 859 |
| 2022-02-01 | a | 508 |
| 2022-02-01 | b | 565 |
| 2022-03-01 | a | 600 |
| 2022-03-01 | b | 474 |
| 2022-04-01 | a | 490 |
| 2022-04-01 | b | 542 |

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide your input as DataFrame constructor or dictionary?

Comment: @mozway `df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2021-11-01','2021-11-01','2021-12-01','2021-01-01','2021-01-01','2022-02-01', '2022-02-01','2022-03-01','2022-03-01','2022-04-04'],\
             'product':['a','b','a','a','a','b','a','b','a','b'],
            'quant':[234,837,930,362,859,0,0,0,0,0]})`

Answer (score 0):

You can use rolling and say that the window should be closed on the left. In code it should read like

```py
df.rolling("3M", closed='left')
```

Comment: rolling function won't be of help here as it takes current row value into consideration. I need to calculate it **without** current row, based on **3 previous ones**

Comment: That's what closed should do. But probably closed right. I didn't have a propper exmaple to test it

Comment: Either lift or right results in ValueError: window must be an integer 0 or greater. Do you mind testing it on this example, please? `df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2021-11-01','2021-11-01','2021-12-01','2021-01-01','2021-01-01','2021-02-01', '2021-02-01','2021-03-01','2021-03-01','2021-04-04'],\
             'product':['a','b','a','a','a','b','a','b','a','b'],
            'quant':[234,837,930,362,859,0,0,0,0,0]})`
I need to keep current values for months 2021-11-01 : 2022-01-01 and moving averages for previous months starting from 2022-02-01